# Sailsjs error handling with database / waterline errors

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I'm building an api that receives webhook data (orders from shopify) and saves them to a relational mysql database. Each order has products in it that belong to collections (categories). I relate the product to the collection, or create a new collection if it doesn't already exist. The problem I run into is that since I can't use [findOrCreate()](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/929) I do a find() first, and then if nothing is found I do a create. However, since nodejs is async, if I get many orders coming in at once, sometimes the same collection isn't found for two different products at the same time, and then one will create it right before the other one tries, so when the other one tries to create it waterline throws an error:

col_id
   • A record with that `col_id` already exists (`405145674`).

What is the best way to catch this error so I can just do another find() so the function returns the proper collection instead of an undefined? I could just do this:

```
if (err){ findmethodagain(); }
```

But then it would try that for any error, not a "record with that id already exists" error.

Comment: Try to inspect error for some unique code or property which is unique to such errors and retry only when such code matches.

Comment: @Sangharsh when I console.log the error it says what the issue is, but I don't know how to get certain parts of the error. Should I just do an err.search('A record with that col_id alreasy exists') or the lodash equivalent?

Comment: When error is logged, only `err.toString()` is displayed. Check other attributes of err, which are not displayed but are useful here. E.g. `err.code`,  `err.toPOJO()`, `err.ValidationError`, `err.originalError`, `err.invalidAttributes`

Comment: @Sangharsh Great! Is there documentation on that somewhere? I'd like to read up.

Comment: Haven't seen documentation on this (which also means error attributes may changes in future release). See https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/issues/40#issuecomment-97460138

Answer (score 0):

If you're not seeing this a lot, it wouldn't hurt to just do a second attempt after a delay. You can use `Promise.delay` from, for example, [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) to run a second function after some number of milliseconds on any error. If in most situations one of them creates the collection, then you'll succeed with just one retry.

If you are seeing lots of other errors, well, fix them.

However, race conditions usually indicate that you need to rework the architecture.  I'd suggest instead of relying on error attributes or trying to hack around them, you redesign it, at least for the situation where you have to create a new collection.  One popular option is to set up a worker queue.  In your case, you would just use `find` in the first pass to see if a collection exists, and if not, kick it off to the queue for a single worker to pick up sequentially.  In the worker job, do your `find` then create.  You can use [Redis](https://redis.io/) and [Bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull) to set this up quickly and easily.